# System.Runtime.Serialization.Json nuget package error on .NetStandard

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2015, nuget-package, .net-standard

I've posted an issue on [.NetStandard repository](https://github.com/dotnet/standard) but they just didn't care for 12 days for now.. So, I wanted to try Stackoverflow. Here is [the link of my issue](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/571).

I've started to use .NetCore version=1.0.0-preview2-003121 with Visual Studio 2015. My project.json file is below:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard2.0": {
      "dependencies": {
        "System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml": "4.3.0",
        "System.Runtime.Serialization.Json": "4.3.0"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My code file is below:

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;

namespace NetCoreTests
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public Class1()
        {
            XmlObjectSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(int));
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the error I get when I try to build the solution:

```
CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer' 
to 'System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer'   NetCoreTests..NETStandard,Version=v2.0
```

Looks like `DataContractJsonSerializer` class in System.Runtime.Serialization.Json nuget package doesn't inherit `XmlObjectSerializer` class in System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml nuget package. I can see that in general there's no dependency between these 2 nuget packages; however, if you check 4 and later versions of .Net Framework `DataContractJsonSerializer` always inherits from `XmlObjectSerializer` because as far as I know every DataContractSerializer inherits from `XmlObjectSerializer`. Even in this repository this inheritance exists:
https://github.com/dotnet/standard/blob/master/netstandard/ref/System.Runtime.Serialization.cs#L332

What can you advice for me about this situation? Am I doin something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the VS 2015 based preview tooling for .NET Core / .NET Standard to try to build for .NET Standard 2.0.

If you use VS 2017 / .NET Core SDK 2.0.0+ then you get the correct reference assemblies to build (which are pulled from the `NETStandard.Library` 2.0.0 NuGet package - the `System.*` packages are trimmed out by msbuild logic if they are referenced).

Your code sample works using a new .NET Standard 2.0 project using tooling that actually supports .NET Standard 2.0 (VS 2017, CLI 2.0.0).

Note that in .NET Standard < 2.0, the `DataContractJsonSerializer` did not inherit from `XmlObjectSerializer` - which is the one you are getting via the referenced NuGet package (since you are missing the tooling that trims out this package and adds correct .NET Standard reference assemblies).

Comment: For .NetStandard2.0 you're right: The code above is working. But for the rest of the versions (between 1.0 - 1.6) it's not working. Looks like it's solved in .NetStandard2.0; but the thing is it's still not working in VS2015; even with .NetStandard2.0 :).

Comment: in < 2.0, it didn't inherit from `XmlObjectSerializer`. You could try using `NETStandard.Library` 2.0.0 instead but again - .net standard 2.0 has a lot of breaking changes and only the new tooling knows how to deal with these

Comment: Yes. But the thing is, even in vs2017 with .NetStandard1.6 + System.Runtime.Serialization.Json nuget package + System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml nuget package it gives error. So it's not related to vs2017, vs2015 or .netstandard versions less than 2.0. It's about the nuget packages. The assemblies in the nuget packages are forcing DataContractJsonSerializer not to inherit from XmlObjectSerializer.

Comment: @martin-ulrich: Please check this configuration (vs2017 + .NetStandard1.6 +System.Runtime.Serialization.Json nuget package + System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml nuget package) and you'll find it reasonable to say "the problem is in the nuget packages" :)

Comment: I wrote above and even added to the answer that for < 2.0, it doesn't inherit from `XmlObjectSerializer`.

Comment: To clarify: `DataContractJsonSerializer` was not of part of .NET Standard before 2.0, there only was an extension NuGet package for .NET Standard ("for" vs "part of"). the version in this NuGet package does not inherit from `XmlObjectSerializer`. In .NET Standard 2.0, the tooling needs to make sure the the new .NET Standard version is used instead of the version in the package.